# Debug GWT using IntelliJ

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I am a question about how to debug GWT using IntelliJ.

I have got a maven GWT project which I can debug in IntelliJ. However, once I changed some GWT class, I have to manually compile it in order for it to take effects.

I know in Eclipse, once a GWT class is changed, by refreshing the web page will automatically update the generated javascript. But IntelliJ doesn't seem to do the same.

Did I misconfig something? Does anyone develop GWT using IntelliJ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of debugging GWT code is using "Out Of Process Hosted Mode", where there is no javascript involved and instead hosted mode communicates to the browser via an extension and dictates how to change the DOM.

See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UsingOOPHM.

If you are using this, IntelliJ is running/debugging a Java server just like any other. Changes to the classes in your project should be hotloaded into a debugged JVM when you save (I assume IntelliJ supports that).

Answer (score 0):

I am using IDEA 12 for develop GWT applications. In my opinion it is works better then Eclipse. Try to run the project as a GWT Module. It is faster and debug works without additional settings.

Answer (score 0):

Note that GWT-integration is included only in the Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ. 
For community edition it's a bit more tricky to get GWT debugging to run properly. But it's doable.

One thing we did here at work was exploding the war and then adding a NTFS Junction Point between the war source folder and the exploded war folder. This will then keep the files in sync and allowed on the fly updates of the various parts of the client.

ie. link between /path/to/source/war -> /path/to/target/exploded/war

Answer (score 0):

**GWT Eclipse dev 101** - Eclipse does not update the javascript when you change java class when you refresh the page. I am dead sure on this.

GWT updates the javascript in eclipse/idea/console only when you execute GWT compiler. We tend tend to avoid as it is productivity kill on large projects.

Please mention which Intellij idea edition you are using community edition or ultimate edition. GWT ultimate edition comes with "native" gwt plugin and works out of the box.

As mentioned my trappski its bit more tricky with community edition and follow his approach.